# Group by mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have collection where each document has user related details. 
userid:1001,abc:1
userid:1001,abc:9
userid:1002,abc:1
userid:1001,abc:3

Something like this.
I wanted to get count of userId which has maximum occurances.
I need to do this on Mongo shell.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you google searched?

Comment: Ofcourse. this is not a straightforward answer. Hence posted it here. I want group by + max count.

Comment: This is the most basic example of aggregation always mentioned in the docs and numerous questions on this site.

Comment: Yes. I get it now , how I can use aggregation for this use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) of mongo. For the answer you can use $group operator to group by userid and sorting them based count. Something like this:

Suppose collection name is test:

db.test.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$userid","occurence":{"$sum":1}}},{$sort:{"occurence":-1}}])

Comment: I think the version of mongo I have does not support aggregate.